# Write script to search the solution

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, batch-file, visual-studio-2013, full-text-search

I'm working on removing a large number of old and unused images from our website.  We run ASP.NET with C# code behind, and do our work out of Visual Studio (2013).  Right now I'm just going through our images directory and searching the solution for the image file name.  While we have some filenames that follow a pattern and can be done in a group using regex, this is still rather tedious.  Is there a way that I can write a batch script (or anything) to search the solution for every file in this directory?  I can imagine pseudocode like

```
for file in images_directory
    if file not in solution
        delete file
```

but is this possible?

Technically we're just moving the files into another folder to be safe, so I guess the actual pseudocode would be more like

```
for file in images_directory
    if file not in solution
        move file to backup_directory
```

Comment: Yes--use Powershell.  Batch is very difficult for this type of thing, and although it could be done in batch, someone else would have to write it and you (and I) probably wouldn't learn anything from it because it is so obtuse.  You can do pretty much anything with Powershell, and it's fairly easy to learn.  You can probably find a Powershell script that does this by Googling "powershell find file and move it".

Comment: @TonyHinkle Yeah, I can do that much.  My main problem is with figuring out how to search the solution using batch or Powershell

Comment: When you say solution are you talking about a .sln or .csproj file? In other words you are checking if the file is included into the project?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I mean a .sln file.  In general what I'm doing is searching the solution using `Ctrl + Shift + F` for each filename, and I'd like to accomplish the same thing using a batch or powershell script.

Comment: In powershell you could try obtaining the file as a string by doing $fileContent = Get-Content 'project.sln' | Out-String then for file in file directory $fileContent -match $filenameRegex or $fileContent -like "\*$filename\*"

Comment: @Dannno - I'm confused. Your pseudo code says you want to delete images that *are* found in the solution, but your description seems to indicate the opposite ("remove old unused images").

Comment: Can you assume all images have unique file names (so we can use the filename without the path)?

Comment: @Rob You're right, updated.  All images are linked to relatively (`'/images/filename.png'`) and although there may be multiple folders that have a `'filename.png'` present, if there are any links to *a* `'filename.png'` then none of them should be removed.

Comment: @Dannno - so would the following work: 1. Scan all source files in your solution, looking for `*.png` (and possibly other image files). This is the "keep" list. 2. Move/Delete any images found under your root folder that don't match anything in the keep list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your solution file, find all references to .csproj files.  Within each .csproj file, find all include lines.  Within each included file, find all lines containing references to images.  Copy each relevant line to a temporary list.  This will make searching faster than searching every .cs file multiple times for every image.

For each graphic file, use `findstr` to perform a regexp search for `/\bfilename\b/i` within the temporary list.  If not found, use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) to initiate a move of the orphaned image to backup.

Save this with a .bat extension, modify the first three `set` lines to appropriate values, and give it a shot.  By default, it only pretends to move.  If you're satisfied that the simulations will produce correct results, remove `echo` from the `move` line near the bottom to let the script off its leash.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "image_dir=c:\path\to\images"
set "sln_file=c:\path\to\solution\Project1.sln"
set "backup_dir=c:\path\to\backup"

set "remember=%temp%\proj_images.txt"   
for %%I in ("%sln_file%") do pushd "%%~dpI"

rem // .sln -> .csproj -> .cs -> images.  Find image references and remember.
del "%remember%" >NUL 2>NUL

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('findstr /i ".csproj\>" "%sln_file%"') do (

    rem // %%I contains lines matching /.csproj\b/ig
    for %%p in (%%I) do if exist "%%~p" (

        rem // %%p contains a .csproj filename
        for /f "delims=" %%J in ('findstr /i "\<include\>" "%%~p"') do (

            rem // %%J contains lines matching /\binclude\b/ig
            for %%c in (%%J) do if exist "%%~c" (

                rem // %%c contains the filename of an include
                findstr /i ".png\> .jpg\> .gif\> .bmp\> .tif\>" "%%~c" >>"%remember%" && (

                    echo Images referenced within %%~nxc.  I'll remember this.
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

rem // for each image file in image_dir (recursive)
for /r "%image_dir%" %%I in (*.png *.jpg *.gif *.bmp *.tif) do (

    rem // regexp test for /\bfilename.ext\b/i
    findstr /i "\<%%~nxI\>" "%remember%" >NUL || (

        rem // non-zero exit status of findstr means not found
        echo %%~nxI is not referenced by any files included in the solution's projects.

        rem // *********************************************************
        rem // REMOVE "ECHO" FROM THE FOLLOWING LINE TO ENABLE THE MOVES
        rem // *********************************************************
        echo move "%%~fI" "%backup_dir%"
    )
)

del "%remember%" >NUL 2>NUL
echo Press any key to exit.
pause >NUL
```

Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

All together If I understand correctly You first want to obtain all images files from directory.  Using PowerShell:

```
$imageFiles = Get-ChildItem 'path/to/image/directory' -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) }
```

This grabs all files excluding Directories.  Then:

```
$solutionText = Get-Content 'path/to/solution/file.csproj' | Out-String
ForEach ($file in $imageFiles ) {
    if ($solutionText -match $file.Name) {
        # Move to another folder
    }
}
```

The only issue is that you'd need to make sure that the filenames don't have a chance of matching elsewhere on the file giving false positives.

Comment: This tells me that none of the images are used, which isn't true.

Comment: Try it on your .csproj file as this is where the included files are normally listed. I've tested on my own project.  2 files were not listed in the .csproj file and sure enough when i opened the project they were not listed in the solution explorer

Comment: All of my files are listed in the solution explorer - they are just never used in any of the actual files.

Comment: the .csproj file holds all the files that are included into you project which you will see in the solution explorer.  If you open it with notepad you will see xml tags like <Content Include="path/to/file" />.  Because the .csproj file contains the information of all the included files.  If you make changes outside of visual studio, that file will not be updated.  So if you move a file without doing it through visual studio, the solution explorer will still show it as included because .csproj still lists it, and it doesn't know it has been moved.

Comment: So will this actually search if the file is used anywhere inside of the html files?  Because everything is already included in my project - I'm removing those that are unnecessarily included (by virtue of not being used by any of the web pages)